# ERROR:Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

I try to get excel sheet names, with oledb.

**My connection string is:**

```
string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

where filepath is a filename.

**My code for this:**

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [Employee$]", conn);
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(Data);
```

**Get an Error in this line**

> adapter.Fill(Data);

**Error is**

> 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: 'Employee$' is not a valid name.  Make sure
>   that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it
>   is not too long.

How can this be Done?

Comment: Is your Excel worksheet named `Employee`?

Comment: yes Excel worksheet name is Employee

Comment: First check entered table name is correct or not.

Comment: @devipriya: Are you sure you are not confusing the WorkBook name with the WorkSheet name?

Comment: no no. i did not know why iam getting this error?? Employee is an xlsx file . I need to import data from excel to Mysql while running i am getting an error like that.

Comment: http://technico.qnownow.com/bulk-copy-data-from-excel-to-destination-db-using-sql-bulk-copy/   this is my reference.

Comment: Did you assign `Thisworkbook.fullpath` to the `path` var?

Comment: Here the textbox contain the path string path = txtfilepath.Text;
string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

Comment: @devipriya: That's exactly what I need to confirm. Is `Employee` name of your Excel **file** or the name of your **sheet**. Check again, if the sheet is named `Sheet1` or `Employee`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dataGridView1_Data$]", conn);
 OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(Data);
```